# have to find the port number for a particular ip address

Tags: unix, port

I need to find the port number of a server, I have the host name and the IP address.
Is this possible?
I need this as when I try to connect to this server through putty its throwing a Network error:Connection refused error, which may be because of the wrong port number

Comment: is it a remote server or a local one (Which you have control over it).

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for the port number the ssh server on that system listens on. Usually that is port 22 (well known ssh port), but you are right, this can be changed in the ssh server configuration. If so there are two possibilities yo have:

1. ask the administrator of the ssh server for the port number
2. make a network scan of the server which shows up all open ports. Note however that this can be regarded as offensive behavior and may be blocked in mid way.

But most likely you are facing another problem: some firewall blocking your requests or the ssh server not listening to request from outside at all.

And a side note: a `server` is a service, often listening on a port, you can interact with it typically by "speaking" a specific protocol. A `system` might refer to a computer running software, typically reachable via network these days. Many servers can be operated on a system. A system can be identified by its ip address. Many people confuse this and speak of a "server" when referring to such a "system" which is simply wrong and creates confusion from a technical point of view.